# PreUpgradeCheck Error How to locate reference of Missing Feature

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am migrating sharepoint 2007 publishing site to sharepoint 2010. For migration process I have followed the steps

```
1. Backup the content database from the SP2007 machine.
2. Restore that database in sql server 2008 (SP2010 machine).
3. Create a new web application in SP2010.
4. I have run the following stsadm command for PreUpgradeCheck in SP2007
```

I am getting the error log as follows
Error: Missing server file or server configuration issues

Server side files are referenced in the content databases, but are not installed on the server. Without these files, the sites may not function completely or the content may not render correctly. Also, upgrade or post upgrade issues may occur if these files are not available in the new version environment.

The following feature(s) are referenced by the content, but they are not installed on the web server

```
Name = Unknown, Feature id = f3dc6c9a-ea83-4c22-bdb9-1a3a178717cf, Reference count = 1, Scope = Web, Status = Missing
Name = Unknown, Feature id = a5977882-1fbc-4b94-a345-c9f3dac1b18c, Reference count = 1, Scope = Web, Status = Missing
```

The link provided below the error explains the issue but doesn't provide any instruction on how to search through the content to find the reference in order to fix it.

For more information about this rule, see KB article 976218 in the rule article list at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=120257.

Could anyone provide a solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

You can search the 12 hive location in your 2007 machine to find the missing feature. Do a text search on `f3dc6c9a-ea83-4c22-bdb9-1a3a178717cf` and the other feature and install it in SharePoint 2010.

You can also use a tool such as `SharePoint Manager 2007` to browse all the features and inspect their ID's but doing a text search will allow you to find the missing feature quickly.